# Show Selected Value in Dropdown

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008, drop-down-menu

I have a form where a record can be viewed and updated. The data is being populated from a stored procedure. Everything populates fine except for my dropdown list. This is my code behind:

```
using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        EmployeeIdTextBox.Text = sdr["EmployeeID"].ToString();
        EmployeeNameTextBox.Text = sdr["EmployeeName"].ToString();
        DepartmentDropDown.DataTextField = sdr["Department"].ToString();
        DepartmentDropDown.DataValueField = sdr["Department"].ToString();
        DepartmentDropDown.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And this is my aspx:

```
<div>
    EmployeeID:
    <asp:TextBox ID="EmployeeIdTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxWidth" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div>
    EmployeeName:
    <asp:TextBox ID="EmployeeNameTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxWidth" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div>
    Department:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DepartmentDropDown" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxWidth"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

I can, however, get the values in the dropdown if I change my aspx like the following, though I would much prefer to do this all on the backend as I have several more fields than shown below.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DepartmentDropDown" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxWidth"
    DataSourceID="SqlDS1" DataTextField="Department" 
    DataValueField="Department" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDS1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Department FROM Employees">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Can I do this all in one step like I'm trying to do, or do I need to do this in two steps? The second half of my issue is that I also need to have the item which corresponds to the user, selected in the dropdown by default. The second method populates the dropdown, though nothing is selected since it's a separate query so there is no correlation to the user data I'm viewing in the form.

Comment: You have to return multiple result sets from database

Comment: in your code behind try : ``DepartmentDropDown.SelectedText= sdr["Department"].ToString()``, you need to databind dropdown in code behind when doing second way just set selected item of dropdownlist

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Error with your suggestion. Dropdown does not contain a definition for SelectedText. I had trid to use SelectedItem.Text but I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I'm not seeing where to databind other than where I am in my first example, which I did with the second as well but no luck.

Comment: bind dropdown also from code behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Solution is posted below for reference...

Code behind:

```
using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        EmployeeIdTextBox.Text = sdr["EmployeeID"].ToString();
        EmployeeNameTextBox.Text = sdr["EmployeeName"].ToString();
        DepartmentDropDown.DataBind();
        DepartmentDropDown.Items.FindByValue(sdr["Department"].ToString()).Selected = true;
    }
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DepartmentDropDown" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxWidth"
    DataSourceID="SqlDS1" DataTextField="Department" 
    DataValueField="Department" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDS1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Department FROM Employees">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```